# Azure Cosmos DB stored procedure: setting partition key from web client?

Tags: rest, postman, azure-cosmosdb

I have a partitioned collection in Cosmos DB.  I'm attempting to execute a stored procedure within this collection using Postman as documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/execute-a-stored-procedure.  When I do this, I encounter the following error:

```
{
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation.\r\nActivityId: 0000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000000, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.19.162.2"
}
```

I have a partition key that I'm sending as a parameter to the stored procedure, and subsequently using in the `WHERE` clause of the query within the procedure, but the API seems to expect the partition key to be passed in some other fashion, i.e., request header?

When using the C# Document DB SDK, the partition key is set as a `RequestOption` as follows:

```
var storedProcedureUri = UriFactory.CreateStoredProcedureUri("MyDB", "MyCol", "MyProc");
var requestOptions = new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(myPartitionKey) };
var procedureResponse = await Client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<MyObjType>(storedProcedureUri, requestOptions);
var document = procedureResponse.Response;

return document;
```

I'm not seeing where/how this request option can be set when executing the procedure from basic web client.

Comment: I’ve seen this in some documentation set as a key on a request header `x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey` - not sure if it’ll work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PartitionKey is required as a request header, along with a few others:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-date", utc_date);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-version", "2017-02-22");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey",
    new PartitionKey(signingDocumentId).ToString());
```

See here for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/common-documentdb-rest-request-headers